# ASP.net Webforms - Name spacing basic controls

Tags: asp.net, webforms

When using a repeater the controls within each repeater item have a unique id

```
<input Id = ctl00_Content_Tabs_ctl00_Tabs_ctl01_Comments />
```

I can access this on the code-behind page like so

```
var ri = rptData.Items[1];
ri.FindControl("Comments");
```

If it possible to apply this to a table row that is not created from a data source?

for example

```
var tr = new TableRow();
var cell = new TableCell();
cell.Controls.Add(new HiddenField(){ ID="PostId", Value=rdr["PostId"] })
tr.Cells.Add(cell);
tblData.Rows.Add(tr)
```

This way I could access the data in each row like this:

```
foreach(TableRow tr in tblData.Rows)
{
  var postid = tr.FindControl("PostId");
}
```

Comment: You should not add control dynamically to Repeater control. Why don't you create HiddeField inside Repeater control at design time.

Comment: I get that idea but I don't want the hidden field in every row.